# Conditional Remember Invalidation

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable that I want to animate in/out of my UI when the type of a class is specific type.

The code looks like this.

```
AnimatedVisibility(currentValue is MyType) {
   if (currentValue is MyType) // required check as MyComposable only takes MyType
        MyComposable(myType = currentValue)
}
```

The problem is this will animate in just fine but it doesn't animate out since when `currentValue` isn't `MyType` the `AnimatedVisibility` composable is empty.

I really need to `remember` the value of `currentValue` whenever it is `MyType` but I don't know how to do this with the standard `remember` calls.

I have a working solution...

```
AnimatedVisibility(currentValue is MyType) {
   val value = currentComposer.cache(currentValue is MyType) { currentValue }

   if (value is MyType)
       MyComposable(myType = value)
}
```

However, the `cache` function used by `remember` is marked explicitly with DO NOT USE.

Is there a way to correctly implement the cache function or maybe a better way to animate the transition?

I could store the value in a `MutableState` and update it in a `SideEffect` but this would lag the value updates by a frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution using only the published API. There may be a more elegant way but here it is.

```
private class Wrapper<T>(var value: T)
@Composable
fun <T> rememberConditionally(condition: Boolean, block: @DisallowComposableCalls () -> T): T? {
    val wrapper = remember { Wrapper<T?>(null) }
    
    if (condition) 
        wrapper.value = block()
    
    return wrapper.value
}
```

When `condition` is true, it will return the new value and update the saved one. When `condition` is false, it will return the value from the last time `condition` was true.

If `condition` was never true, it will return null.